# Data Mining / ML applications in hydrodynamics?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

I have a question about Scientific Data Mining.

1. Do you know successful case studies of applying Data Mining / Machine Learning techniques in hydrodynamics?
2. In general, does it make actually sense to try to apply DM/ML techniques to such deterministic systems as gas/fluid flows which are described by Navier-Stokes equations?

I guess that answer is 'no' in the case of very simple flows. But maybe it makes sense if we have a deal with complex data from turbulent/multiphase/... flows?

1. What could be the problem formulation in this area?

I will appreciate to your opinion, links to the papers and web-pages.

Answer (score 1):

There has been quite a lot of work done regarding the statistical description of turbulence, trying to find correlations between certain quantities (pressure, velocity components) and the autocorrelation (in time) of these quantities.

There has been some research done on the spectral analysis of turbulence as well.

But there isn't that much insight to be gained from this statistical description of turbulence, and it has little application in terms of computing turbulent flows.

There has been some data mining work done with ships to try and find the drag coefficients of ships hulls depending on the ships parameter and speed. This results in methods for approximating a ship's drag such as the Hollenbach method. But these regressions have their limits and are only good for very rough estimations.